# Cannot load country-specific resource

Tags: iphone, ios5, localization

I am loading text resources in different languages from text files using:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myfile" ofType:@"txt"];

if(filePath) {

    NSString *myText = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

}
```

Works very well with my language specific resources in English, German etc.

But I do also have some country-specific resources, like an English text for United Kingdom, an English text for USA, a German text for Austria etc.

I would expect these resources to be loaded if the phone is set to the specific country (Region Format), but they don't. The filepath will always be set to the file in the "pure" language folder.

So for example I have myfile.txt in the folders:

```
en.lproj
en-GB.lproj
en-US.lproj
```

but it always loads the one in en.lproj

Folders have been created using the localization function in Xcode and are all located in the same folder.

What is a bit odd is that these folders created by Xcode do seperate language and country by a hyphen, but according to the documentation it should be an underscore. I have tried to copy folders (with underscores) into the project manually, but it still doesn't work.

How do I manage to load the country-specific files?

Thanks.....

Answer (score 3):

I created a "dutch-netherlands" translation of Localisations.string and set iPhone language to dutch, but NSLocalizedString always returned the English translation. The solution was to create a "dutch" translation (nl.lproj) instead of "dutch-netherlands"  (nl-NL.lproj).

In the settings screen of iOS4 or iOS5, you can select Dutch language but there's no subselection for Dutch-Netherlands or Dutch-Belgium, even though these are available in XCode.  It seems to me that XCode offers more translation options than that are actually supported by iOS.

I mean there's no way to make your app use "nl-NL" resources. I guess the same problem goes for German and Austria ("de-DE" and "de-AT").

Comment: You'd better create another question with corresponding link.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Your code sample is a complicated way of loading text resources. It's fine if you are loading non-string resources such as images or media files, but for simple strings it's much easier to just use one `.strings` file per language (containing multiple localized strings) and call `NSLocalizedString` to get the relevant language version of a given string.

**Answer:** The iOS setting under "Region Format" does not affect resource loading. Instead it controls how the system performs locale-dependent functionality (such as date/number formatting and parsing). The iOS setting that controls which language version of your localized resources gets loaded is the Language setting (General > International > Language). Currently, it includes only two English variants: "English" and "British English".

Comment: I do also use the .string files for loading strings, but my application does display some multiple line texts and I do find it more convenient to keep each text in an individual file for each language. Anyway, it did not seem to work for .strings either when I tried to put in a country specific text.

Comment: I am very new to iPhone development and have been using the book "Beginning IOS 5 Development. It says: "When a localized application needs to load a resource - such as an image, property list, or nib - the application checks the user's language and region and looks for the localized folder that matches that setting. If it finds one, it will load the localized version of the resource instead of the base version." I interpret this as I would get the country specific version (as it also does in Java), but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe that is wrong. Only the languages listed in the iOS Language settings are supported for resource loading. Region Format doesn't come into it. So British English should work but not German for Austria. In XCode, you can choose a language if you use the Localization control, I believe you will also only see one version of German there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with nl-NL.lproj (Netherland) and ca-ES.lproj (Catalan). The solution for me is add the language using Xcode. Go to Xcode Project, and then in Info Tab add the langugages. Automatically will create the folders nl-NL.lproj and ca-ES.lproj.

Then you can try this on Simulator (Xcode version 4.6) and these languages don't word, instead will load English language.

First rename manually the folder nl-NL.lproj to nl.lproj. 
Finally go to file {MY_PROJECT}.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj and replace the PATH of the following lines:

```
    C3D2888817108DDA00CE8AC2 /* nl-NL */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = "nl-NL"; path = "nl.lproj/Localizable.strings"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
    C3D2888917108DE500CE8AC2 /* nl-NL */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = text.plist.strings; name = "nl-NL"; path = "nl.lproj/InfoPlist.strings"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

That's all, now I can get these languages settings correctly.