# Adding localization with language identifier to an ipad app

Tags: objective-c, localization, internationalization, ios7, xcode5

I'am coding an iPad app using Xcode. I use Base Internationalization for Storyboards.

So far, I have successfully added many languages, French, English, Spanish.

When trying to add Romanian using Xcode, the process is exactly the same, except the proposed language code is a little bit longer: ro-RO, where French is fr and English en and Splanish es.

No problem so far.

When running the app on the iDevice, I change the system language to Romanian, but my app will keep the last language set, whatever I do.

I suspected something about the longer language code. I've been using git diff to figure out what changes Xcode makes to project files when adding a language support. I see nothing anormal.

I noticed the same with Portugese, wich is pt-PT, so I think the bug has something to do with locales containing a language identifier (_XX).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that XCode supports language-country codes, even though iOS devices can only work with language codes. The easiest way to fix this I think is to close XCode and go to the Finder, and change the folders "pt-PT.lproj" to "pt.lproj" and "ro-RO.lproj" to "ro.lproj" etc.

Also see this related question: [Cannot load country-specific resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268609/cannot-load-country-specific-resource/12887009#12887009)