# Flemish Localization in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, internationalization

I need to add flemish (flamand language) in my project localizations.
I didn't found it.

I found that we can use Nederland, but I'm not sure.
Does someone got an idea ?

I'm putting (Dutch Belgium) at this time, but once again, i'm not sure.
Many thx

Comment: Is Flemish a dialect of Dutch? If so, go ahead and use it. If not... then apparently this language is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Flemish is the same as Dutch-Belgium: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flemish.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask your client what they mean with Flemish, but I've had trouble getting a Dutch-Netherlands translation to appear at all on a device, but just "Dutch" worked fine.

So I think it's best to just add "Dutch" (=nl) translation, and not use Dutch-Belgium (=nl-BE). You should do some testing, but both Dutch speaking users from The Netherlands and Belgium should see the translation then.

Also see: [Cannot load country-specific resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268609/cannot-load-country-specific-resource/12887009#12887009)